# Вывести массив в DataTable C++

Tags: visual-c++

Есть линейный массив данных, есть DataTable, BindingSource и DataGridView.

```
for (char x = 1; x < fuel->Columns->Count - 1; x++) {
            for (char y = 1; y < fuel->Rows->Count - 1; y++) {
                i = rx_msg[1].Data[c];
            //  i = 14.7 * 128 / i; //' convert to afr
                //  i = System.Math.Round(i, 1) //'round to 1 dec pl
                fuel->Rows[y]->ItemArray[x] = i;



                DebugBox->Text += fuel->Rows[y]->ItemArray[x] + " \r\n";


                c = c + 1;
            }
        }
```

В дебагбокс выводятся пробелы, в датагриде пусто, проект перенес из вб дот нет. Датагрид читается из хмл схемы если это важно, подозреваю что проблема связана с типами величин.

Comment: Ну, раз никто не отвечает... Вместо `fuel->Rows[y]->ItemArray[x]` попробуйте `fuel->Rows[y]->default[x]` или `fuel->Rows[y]->Item[x]`.

Comment: Item нету уже пробовал, завтра попробую дефолт свойство. Вопрос, а обязательно ли объявлять датасет?

Comment: нет таких свойств, это c++

Comment: Это не C++. Это C++/CLI - совершенно другой язык. И, как видите по количеству ответов, абсолютно непопулярный и малоиспользуемый. В последних версиях Visual Studio вообще нет шаблонов таких проектов. И лично у меня нет желания искать и устанавливать их, чтобы помочь вам (думаю, как и большинству). Документация для этого языка очень плохая; найти ответы на форумах почти нереально. Поэтому либо переходите на язык C# (если пишете на платформе .NET), либо используйте "чистый" C++ (тогда придётся отказаться от Windows Forms).

Comment: Отказаться от вин формы не могу, от цпп бы отказался но нужно в неуправляемую длл передавать по ссылке весьма своеобразные структуры со ссылками, в си шарм с этим тоже плохо

Comment: нюанс, если прогнать алгоритм дважды то в таблице данные появляются...

Comment: Вот так работает     `DataGridView1->Rows[y]->Cells[x]->Value = i;
  
   DebugBox->Text += fuel->Rows[y]->ItemArray[x] + " \r\n";`

Comment: Оформите свой комментарий как ответ. И тем не менее, я бы на вашем месте GUI писал на C#, а на C++/CLI оформил бы лишь обёртку над неуправляемой dll.

Comment: я так не умею, я функциональщик,